# Android Studio crashes when uses Melos

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, melos

Flutter project. When AS tries to index project it is broken with exception below. It makes AS useless. It has started after installing Melos.

Dart Plugin - 213.7371
AS - 2021.3.1

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exclude folder file://C:/Dev/Projects/mobile-websales-git/.dart_tool must be under content entry file://C:/Dev/Projects/mobile-websales-git/.
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.roots.ModifiableContentEntryBridge.addExcludeFolder(ModifiableContentEntryBridge.kt:111)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.module.roots.ModifiableContentEntryBridge.addExcludeFolder(ModifiableContentEntryBridge.kt:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootModificationUtil.lambda$updateExcludedFolders$12(ModuleRootModificationUtil.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootModificationUtil.lambda$updateModel$9(ModuleRootModificationUtil.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootModificationUtil.modifyModel(ModuleRootModificationUtil.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootModificationUtil.updateModel(ModuleRootModificationUtil.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModuleRootModificationUtil.updateExcludedFolders(ModuleRootModificationUtil.java:161)
    at com.jetbrains.lang.dart.DartStartupActivity.excludeBuildAndToolCacheFolders(DartStartupActivity.java:97)
    at com.jetbrains.lang.dart.DartStartupActivity.lambda$runActivity$2(DartStartupActivity.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:196)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
...
```